# docker tini causes no such file or directory error

Tags: docker

Currently building an image using the following docker file

```
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
FROM node:16 AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy node.js source and build, changing owner as well
COPY --chown=node:node . /usr/src/app
ENV npm_config_cache=/usr/src/app
RUN npm ci && npm run package


FROM node:16 AS production
ARG CC_SERVER_PORT

# Setup tini to work better handle signals
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.19.0
ENV PLATFORM=amd64
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini-${PLATFORM} /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /usr/src/app/npm-shrinkwrap.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN npm ci --omit=dev && npm cache clean --force

ENV PORT $CC_SERVER_PORT
EXPOSE $CC_SERVER_PORT
ENV NODE_ENV=production

USER node
ENTRYPOINT [ "/tini", "--", "/usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

build goes through successfully, but while in the kubernetes cluster, container failing with error

```
exec /tini: no such file or directory
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You shouldn't need to install `tini` in the image – just run the container with `docker run --init ...`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an issue because I was building the image on a Mac M1, which has an ARM64 architecture. However, my cluster had a Linux AMD64 architecture. To resolve the issue, I needed to specify the platform while building the image.

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/